# Libgdx Android error native libraries

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to run ma game on android device and i have these errors:

```
The library 'jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
The following libraries were found:
libjinput-linux.so
libjinput-linux64.so
```

What can i do to fix this error? Please help.

Newest Libgdx 1.5.5, phone with android 2.3.7.

Comment: Your android version is too old. Try using an Emulator. Genymotion for instance.

Comment: I'd say that this error message is pretty clear.  You're using native libraries  that cannot be used on the device that you're attempting to run it on.  You'd need to find another library that's supported and refactor your code accordingly.  Good luck!

Comment: What Android device are you using?